# How to keep someone from inputting a certain value on a java method?

Tags: java, methods, integer

I have this method:

```
public static int getSlotFromRow(int row, int slot)
```

Imagine this as getting the slot from a row in a certain data table.

Each row has 9 slots and the maximum rows is 6. I want this method to return an integer that tells me the slot (for example, if i want the 3rd slot on the 4th row, the method would return 30).

But how do I keep someone from inputting an integer bigger than 6 on the row variable and an integer bigger than 9 on the slot variable when they are using the method?

Comment: You simply validate the value before passing it to your method...

Comment: Your method is also pretty confusing as you are sending a slot # TO the method, but asking for a different slot # to be returned?

Comment: What does the client code using the method look like? Does the call come from an user interface?

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options.  The most widely used is to validate the values passed to the method within the method itself:

```
    public static int getSlotFromRow(int row, int slot) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        // Verify the values are valid
        if (row < 1 || row > 6) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid row selected!");
        }
        if (slot < 1 || slot > 9) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid slot selected!");
        }

        return 30; // Or whatever calculation you do to come up with 30
    }
```

You could also do the validation before calling the method at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use `throw` to throw an `Exception`. In this particular case, `IllegalArgumentException` seems appropriate as the caller has provided an argument that violates the method's precondition:

```
public void getSlotFromRow(int row, int slot) {
    if(row>6){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("value of argument 'row' too large");
    }
    if(slot>9){
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("value of argument 'slot' too large");
    }
}
```